# Creating a new repo/project from a previous cloned project

Tags: git, repository, git-push, git-init

I cloned an existing repo from Git (Bitbucket) and copied that file to a new location. Now I wanted to push that to an empty repository to Bitbucket as a new project with changes that are related to that project. This happened:

```
git remote add origin
fatal: remote origin already exists
```

After that I checked the git version (with $ git remote -v) and it indicates to the original cloned git repo from the last project. Is there a way to remove the git history so that I can do git init and push the project to a new repo? If I use **rm -rf .git** will that harm the original cloned git repo? Or can I then initialize the new project and push that to the new empty repo?

Answer (score 2):

### Description

The reason why you are getting this

> `fatal: remote origin already exists`

is because `origin` is a local version of a remote repository. Think of it as a folder with a name `origin`.

### Example

Just change the name when you add a remote

```
git remote add <name> <url>
```

You can use whatever name you like, as long as it doesn't violate conditions applied by the *file system*

Alternatively, you can remove the `remote` origin.

```
git remote rm origin
```

***Note***: *This will remove local copy of a remote repository named `origin` from your file system!*

### Reference

[git-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

Comment: You are most welcome!  If you are satisfied with any of the answers, could you please accept one of them to show the question has been answerd? :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside .git you store everthing related to your local clone of a git repository. In your case it should be no problem to delete it and rerun git init . after. Once you have done this you have to commit your complete folder …. so your commands could look like (pseudo)

```
$ cd new_project
$ rm -rf .git
$ git init .
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "Initial commit of my fork"
$ git remote add … 
$ git push
```

However, this would purge the complete history of the base of your fork. I would consider this bad style and might conflicts with copyright depending on license original project is used. why not conside a full fork and do something like:

```
$ cd original_repo
$ git remote add -f myfork <bitbucketurl>
$ git push myfork
```

After that has be done you can either remove the original origin from your clone or just reclone from bitbucket. This would keep original history.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add a new remote (`git remote add new_origin destination`), or rename the actual (`git remote rename origin old_origin`), or delete the actual (`git remote rm actual_destination`).